# How to select rows that is >= 1 DAY ago?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

A user can get at max 5 reports before i ban him for 1 day from the chat, when row from this user reach 5 reports i store a `date` on the row, and i can unban him after 1 day with the sql `data < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`.

But this way he is not able to be "unbanned" from the chat, if he does not loggin on their account until 47:99 hours, because the `INTERVAL 1 DAY` will not work. So how can i make a `WHERE` clause to match a row that is at least 1 DAY ago or that is >= 1 DAY ago? It's possible?

```
$link_id = $_SESSION['linkN'];
$deletReport = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM `report_public_chat` WHERE `link_id` = :link_id AND `data` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)");
$deletReport->bindParam(":link_id", $link_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$deletReport->execute();
```

Comment: Use between "current date" and "current date + 24hrs"

Comment: Your current query already does match a date which is at least 1 day ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use delete condition like

```
WHERE date >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

OR

```
WHERE timediff(now(), my_datetime_field) < '24:00:00'
```

Comment: `DATE_ADD(now(),interval -1 day)` is exactly the same as `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 hours)`

```
DELETE FROM `report_public_chat` WHERE `link_id` = :link_id AND `data` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 hours) and `data`<NOW()
```